# Does my vessel's speed affect the rate at which it floods?

Tags: world-of-warships

Enemy hits, especially from torpedoes, can give my vessel the "flooding" status, where damage slowly accumulates over time.

Is this a constant rate of damage, or can I mitigate it by (for example) slowing down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flooding damage reduces ship's fighting capability by 0.66-0.12% of total HP per second, depending on ship's tier. Higher-tier ships receive less damage as % of their health than do low-tier ships. [Source](http://wiki.wargaming.net/en/Torpedoes_(WoWS)).

Slowing down your ship will not changes this, but your ship will slow down on its own because you are taking on water(around 15-20%), making further maneuverability and escaping the situation difficult.

If you are in a Battleship you can use your Repair Party consumable to recover nearly all of the flooding damage you take.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a source for the information that flooding impedes manoeuvrability? I wasn't aware of this, and hadn't noticed it. And it's not clear then whether that returns when the flooding status expires, or what...

Comment: I added source for the information on the damage. As for the maneuverability effect, I don't have any hard numbers on how much it decreases, but it definitely does (and is easy for you to confirm yourself), when the flooding stops. you no longer are taking on water, so your speed returns to normal.

Comment: Huh. That only slightly makes sense... but that's true of most of the physics in this game :)

Comment: having your speed permanently hindered after flooding is more realistic yes, but from a balance and fun point? not so much.